# Primary ideals of localizations

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ be a ring and let $S\subset A$ be a multiplicatively closed set. If we denote by $f$ the canonical map from $A$ to $S^{-1}A$ which takes $x$ to $x/1$, then for any **primary** ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\cap S=\emptyset$, we have a primary ideal of $S^{-1}A$, given by the extension $f(\mathfrak{p})\subset S^{-1}A$ of $\mathfrak{p}$. Is it true that that $f^{-1}(f(\mathfrak{p}))=\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: There have been posters in the past that confused the terms "prime" and "primary". Could you let us know for sure which one you mean? Thanks

Comment: I mean **primary**, not prime.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a prime $a\in f^{-1}(f(P))$, there exists $x$ in $P$ such that $f(a)=f(x)$, we deduce that $f(x-a)=0$ and there exists $s\in S$ such that $s(x-a)=0$. This implies that $sa=sx\in P$. since $P$ is a prime, $a\in P$ or $s^n\in P, n>0$, but $S\cap P$ is empty and $s^n\in S$ since $S$ is a multiplicative family, so $a\in P$. We deduce that $f^{-1}(f(P))\subset P$ and  henceforth is $P$.

Comment: I decided to use the bold letters just for this reason...

Comment: Where's the *primary* ideal?

Comment: @Bernard are you speaking with me?

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro: No, I was asking the question to the author of the answer (I didn't downvote).

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide If I'm not wrong the product $sx$ can belong to $P$ also if we have $x^n\in P$.

Comment: read carefully the definition of a primary ideal.